# hibernate foreign key mapping to unique key

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to us non-primary key as foreign key in my application. Here is the scenario:
I have EMPLOYEE and EMPLOYEE_PROPERTIES tables. There is one-to-many relationship between Employee and Employee properties. Here is my Schema:

---

```
create table employee(
 fname varchar2(100) not null,
 lname varchar2(100) not null,
 emp_id number not null
);
ALTER TABLE employee ADD constraint employee_pk PRIMARY KEY (fname, lname);
alter table employee add constraint employee_uniue unique (emp_id);

create table employee_property(
 emp_prop_id not null,
 emp_id number not null,
 property_name varchar2(100) not null,
 property_value varchar2(100) not null
);
ALTER TABLE employee_property ADD constraint employee_property_pk PRIMARY KEY (emp_prop_id);
ALTER TABLE employee_property ADD CONSTRAINT emp_prop_fk FOREIGN KEY (emp_id) REFERENCES employee(emp_id);
```

---

Here are my hibernate mapping xmls:
-----------------Employee------------------------

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.persistence.vo.Employee" table="EMPLOYEE">
        <composite-id>
            <key-property name="fName" column="FNAME"/>
            <key-property name="lName" column="LNAME"/>
        </composite-id>
        <property name="empId" type="long" access="field" unique="true">
            <column name="EMP_ID" />
        </property>
        <set name="employeeProperties" table="employee_properties" lazy="false"
            fetch="select" cascade="save-update, delete-orphan">
            <key>
                <column name="emp_id" not-null="true"/>
            </key>
            <one-to-many entity-name="com.persistence.vo.EmployeeProperty"/>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

---

-------------------Employee Properties---------------------

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.persistence.vo.EmployeeProperty" table="EMPLOYEE_PROPERTY">
        <id name="empPropId" type="long">
            <column name="EMP_PROP_ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
    <many-to-one name="employee" class="com.persistence.vo.Employee" fetch="select">
        <column name="empId" not-null="true"/>
    </many-to-one>
        <property name="propertyName" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="PROPERTY_NAME" />
        </property>
        <property name="propertyValue" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="PROPERTY_VALUE" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

---

-----------Employee.java-------------------------

```
public class Employee {

    private long empId;
    private String fName;
    private String lName;

    private Set<EmployeeProperty> employeeProperties;
}
```

------------EmployeeProperty.java-------------------

```
public class EmployeeProperty {

    private long empPropId;
    private Employee employee;
    private String propertyName;
    private String propertyValue;
}
```

---

I keep getting following exception when I try to access Employee:
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FKF28BCC4680C757C:EMPLOYEE_PROPERTY [emp_id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (EMPLOYEE [FNAME,LNAME])

Is it possible to reference non-primary key as your foreign key?

Comment: is there any reason why you wouldn't make emp_id a PK? the composite key using fname and lname is probably not a good idea - there are many John Millers in this world afterall.

Comment: yes, in this particular example it make sense to have empId as primary key. But this is just an example I wrote down. I'm working to legacy system where the primary key is composite key with diff 5 columns. I'm planning to replace that with sigle id. But there are some other foreign key references to this composite key that I;ll have to remove too. I was just thinking going forward can I just create unique id column and use that as foreign key for all new tables that I'll be adding.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused by your mappings. Employee to EmployeeProperty is a one-to-many but emp_id in EmployeeProperty is marked in your mappings as the ID field (i.e. PK, Unique column) for this entity?

You have various options:

[1] Add another field to EmployeeProperty to act as the ID e.g. emp_property_id

[2] Make EmployeeProperty an Embeddable (no persistence identity of its own) rather than an Entity

Given that EmployeeProperty is dependant on Employee (i.e. an EmployeeProperty cannot exist independently of an Employee), the 2nd option is probably more correct.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Embeddables

Comment: In my case I can make changes add emp_property_id for my property table. But the properties are not Embeddable. There can by multiple properties for Employee and I dont want to keep adding columns in Employee table for each property. I was just wondering if I can use unique key as foreign key.

Comment: That does not mean you can't use Embeddable. You simply map as an ElementCollection (CollectionOfElements in Hibernate specific API). See 2.7 in previous link: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Embeddables#Collections